# Html form input

Tags: html, forms

I have a form that I want to submit to a url. I am not sure what is the best way to build it. I want to pass dates to and from. I have 3 select boxes, one for date, month and year.

Would I use javascript, php or will the form be built automatically from the intput boxes I have the date in.

Example URL, it is only the date_start & date_end that will change:
https://www.mysite.com/availability/?from=facebook&date_start=2011-08-10&date_end=2011-08-11"

```
    <div class="searchbox-wrapper">
          <p>Date of Arrival:</p>
    <p><select onchange="bke_update_dropdown(form, form.bke_arrival_day.value,
                   form.bke_arrival_month.value,
                   form.bke_arrival_year.value, '1')" class="bke_drop" name="bke_arrival_day" gtbfieldid="8"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15" selected="selected">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select>

    <select onchange="bke_update_dropdown(form, form.bke_arrival_day.value,
                     form.bke_arrival_month.value,
                     form.bke_arrival_year.value, '1')" class="bke_drop" name="bke_arrival_month" gtbfieldid="9"><option value="1">Jan</option><option value="2" selected="selected">Feb</option><option value="3">Mar</option><option value="4">Apr</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">Jun</option><option value="7">Jul</option><option value="8">Aug</option><option value="9">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12">Dec</option></select>

    <select onchange="bke_update_dropdown(form, form.bke_arrival_day.value,
                     form.bke_arrival_month.value,
                     form.bke_arrival_year.value, '1')" class="bke_drop" name="bke_arrival_year" gtbfieldid="10"><option value="2011" selected="selected">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2013">2013</option></select>


        </p>
          <p>Date of Departure:</p>
      <p><select class="bke_drop" name="bke_departure_day" gtbfieldid="11"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16" selected="selected">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select>

    <select class="bke_drop" name="bke_departure_month" gtbfieldid="12"><option value="1">Jan</option><option value="2" selected="selected">Feb</option><option value="3">Mar</option><option value="4">Apr</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">Jun</option><option value="7">Jul</option><option value="8">Aug</option><option value="9">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12">Dec</option></select>

    <select class="bke_drop" name="bke_departure_year" gtbfieldid="13"><option value="2011" selected="selected">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2013">2013</option></select>


        </p>
          <p>Rate Code:&nbsp;
    <input type="text" value="(optional)" onclick="if (this.value == '(optional)') this.value = '';" style="text-align: center;" class="bke_drop" maxlength="10" size="8" name="bke_ratecode" gtbfieldid="14">
    </p>
          <p class="submit-wrapper"><input type="submit" class="date_input" value="Check Rates"></p>
    </div>

    </form>     
</div>
```

Comment: The question is there: Would I use javascript, php or will the form be built automatically from the intput boxes I have the date in.

Comment: Are you asking how to populate the form components with the values in the request parameters if accessing your page with an URL like `https://www.mysite.com/availability/?from=facebook&date_start=2011-08-10&date_end=2011-08-11"`? Maybe you want to submit to that URL with the dates provided in your form?

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear on this, I want to submit the form to the above url as. For date_start I have the inputs of date, month and year. How do I get this inputs into the submitted url for date_start. What would be best javascript, php or something else. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit your `<form>` in such a way that targets to a request like this

```
https://www.mysite.com/availability/?from=facebook&date_start=2011-08-10&date_end=2011-08-11"
```

I'd suggest putting all those fields you have outside the `<form>` tag, and include only `<input type="hidden">` fields in it, so that they are the ones posted when you submit it.
All attributes in the form (in this case the three hidden ones) will be automatically appended to the requested URL (the one in the `action` attribute in the `<form>`).

You can make up the `start_date` and `end_date` fields with javascript in an `onclick` event handler in the `<input type="submit">`

```
<!-- All the current fields here -->

<form action="https://www.mysite.com/availability/" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="facebook">
    <input type="hidden" name="date_start" id="date_start">
    <input type="hidden" name="date_end" id="date_end">
    <input type="submit" onclick="makeUpDates()">
</form>

<script>
    function makeUpDates(){
        // concantenate values to date_start and date_end hidden inputs
        document.getElementById('date_start').value = 
                      form.bke_arrival_year.value + '-' +
                      form.bke_arrival_month.value + '-' +
                      form.bke_arrival_day.value ;
        document.getElementById('date_end').value = 
                      form.bke_departure_year.value + '-' +
                      form.bke_departure_month.value + '-' +
                      form.bke_adeparture_day.value ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking something like this but wasn't sure was it the best way.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) You could also check the date fields in the `makeUpDates` function so that they are not empty, and if any of them is empty, toss an `alert` and make the function return false. Then using `onclick="return makeUpDates();"` will prevent form submission if `makeUpDates()` returns false.

Answer (score 1):

what i would recommend i to actually use a 'submit' button in this instance, since you have so many pieces of data that need to be set BEFORE the request goes to the server.  (also, format your code better so it's more readable.  this alone will do more to help you develop your code more easily.

the process appears to be 'set a bunch of dropdowns and fire those settings off to server'.  so do exactly that.  i'd get rid of the onChange events in your select lists and just drive a single JavaScript function from the 'submit' button that just reads what the select dropdowns are set to, dumps them into and HTTPRequest and sends it to whatever PHP script is running on the server.

bing, bang, boom, you're done.  if the server sends a response, then deal with that separately.

WR!